# Sending Variable from one function to another php function

Tags: php

I am trying to send a variable from a public function to a private static function as follows:

```
public function getAirportFare($fare) {

    $fare2 = 1000;

    return self::getFinalFare($fare, $fare2);

}
```

TO:

```
private static function getFinalFare($fare, $fare2) {

    $fare = $fare + $fare2;

    $final_fare = ($fare * self::$fare_factor);

    if (self::$str_wait_return == "true") {
        $final_fare = $final_fare * 2;
    }

    if (self::$str_return == "true" && self::$return_date != "false" && self::$return_time != "false") {

        // We need to calc to fare based on the return date and time
        $return_fare = self::getFare(1);

        // Append to final fare
        $final_fare = $final_fare + $return_fare;

    }

    return number_format($final_fare,2);

}
```

but $fare2 in the getFinalFare function is undefined? I was just wondering how I can pass this value?

Comment: Try declaring the full class name instead of `self`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in particular; have you tried adding `var_dump($fare2)` in both functions to debug?

Comment: Should not be possible. The variable is declared in the function signature, it *cannot* be undefined. Please show a complete executable code sample and how you determine it's undefined. First hint: are those methods in the same class?

Comment: They are in the same class, I've just done a var_dump in both are the response = NULL // 17.00

Answer (score 0):

Im going to work on the assumption that these two methods are in the same class if not please let me know and i'll update my answer.

What your going to want to do is as follows.

```
public function getAirportFare($fare) {

$fare2 = 1000;

return static::getFinalFare($fare, $fare2);
```

}

this will use the static method inside the class regardless if the class is ever refactored or renamed.

Comment: They are in the same Class, I've tried this and did a var_dump($fare2) and it shows: NULL // 17.00